# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Rglpk

Tags: r, linux, cran, glpk

I have installed the R package "Rglpk" manually in following manner as `root` user on ec2-instance of `Redhat 7`:

```
mkdir -p GLPK
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/glpk-4.47.tar.gz
tar xvf glpk-4.47.tar.gz
cd glpk-4.47
./configure --prefix=/home/ec2-user/GLPK
make
make install
cd ..

wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rglpk_0.6-3.tar.gz
tar xvf Rglpk_0.6-3.tar.gz
mv glpk-4.47 /home/ec2-user/Rglpk/src/GLPK
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/GLPK/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/GLPK/lib
export CPATH=/home/ec2-user/GLPK/include
R CMD INSTALL Rglpk
```

The issue is when i am calling this library in `R` cli with root as user,it works fine but when i switch to my user i.e. `ec2-user` and once call this library in `R` cli ,it starts giving following error for all users,even for root.

```
library("Rglpk")
Loading required package: slam
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rglpk’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/Rglpk/libs/Rglpk.so':
  libglpk.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file is still present in that location:

```
0(ec2-user@resuerdsfdfsfdn02 [~])$ cd /usr/lib64/R/library/Rglpk/libs/
0(ec2-user@resuerdsfdfsfdn02 [/usr/lib64/R/library/Rglpk/libs])$ ls
Rglpk.so*
```

Comment: Autotools does not properly configure the program it is building. You need to properly configure the library. Your `LDFLAGS` should include `-Wl,-R,/home/ec2-user/GLPK/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. Then you won't need hacks like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that have plagued Linux for the last 20 years or so.

Comment: @jww,i am quite new to programming paradigm of R and inherent language,will you kindly explain in detail what these flags are and  supported materials.Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that libglpk.so.0 isn't in the path in the RStudio server's R environment, even though it's in the R environment that you call from your terminal session. It's less than ideal, but a solution is to put the following line in your .Rprofile file:

> dyn.load("/home/ec2-user/GLPK/lib/libglpk.so.0")

This will load the shared library from the path you've specified, instead of having R infer the path from your environment. If your RStudio-server is being run from a different account than the default ec2-user profile on your instance, just replace 'ec2-user' in the above path with whatever username you're using. Once that's done, you should be able to call 'Rglpk' from your RStudio-server session.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue lies that whenever `Rglpk` or any other R packages are called,they are not able to find files such as `libglpk.so.0` as the environment variables were executed locally which points to location of it till the user `cli` exists.Thus **set the environment variables system-wide** so that this library can access irrespective of users:

1)Edit `/etc/bashrc`

2)Place the following variables in it at last:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/GLPK/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/GLPK/lib
export CPATH=/home/ec2-user/GLPK/include
```

3)Reload the file:

```
source /etc/bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience `dyn.load` loads the package but is not enough for using functions. So I use:

```
dyn.load("/home/ec2-user/GLPK/lib/libglpk.so.40") 
Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH=paste0(Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"), ":", "/home/ec2-user/GLPK/lib"))
```

For INSTALL I had to use:

```
export PKG_CFLAGS='-I/home/user/GLPK/include'
export PKG_LIBS='-L/home/user/GLPK/lib'
```